# Realizar un select y guardarlo en un variable para realizar un calculo y guardarlo en otra tabla dentro de un Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql-workbench

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `bsp_alta_turnos1`(
            pFecha_Inicio date,pFecha_Fin date,pId_Medico smallint,pId_Paciente int,pId_OS tinyint,pPrecio_Final float,pId_Espacio smallint)
SALIR:BEGIN`
DECLARE pId_Turno int;
DECLARE pPrecio_Final INT;



 DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS monto;    
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE monto AS    
( SELECT Precio FROM clinicav32.precio p
INNER join  clinicav32. n_afiliados a on a.Id_OS = p.Id_OS
INNER join  clinicav32.medicos m on m.Id_Especialidad = p.Id_Especialidad
INNER join  clinicav32.especialidades e on m.Id_Especialidad = e.Id_Especialidad
where (p.Id_Especialidad =  m.Id_Especialidad  and p.Id_OS = pId_OS and  m.Id_Medico = pId_Medico  and a.Id_Paciente = pId_Paciente  ));
select Precio from monto ;
```

Hasta acá, el resultado que me devuelve es el que necesito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`

Ahora bien ese resultado quiero guardarlo en una variable e insertarlo en un tabla, esto sería la continuación del código de esta forma:

```
 select Precio from monto ;
    set pPrecio_Final = Precio;

START TRANSACTION;


    INSERT INTO clinicav32.turnos VALUES(0,pId_Paciente,pId_Medico,pId_Espacio,pId_OS,pFecha_Inicio, pFecha_Fin,now(),pPrecio_Final);
         SET pId_Turno = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    SELECT CONCAT('OK', pId_Turno) AS Mensaje;


COMMIT; 

END
```

Intenté hacerlo y no pude lograrlo, espero se entienda y puedan ayudarme . Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Con el siguiente código pude solucionarlo acá lo dejo

```
set pPrecio_Final = (select Precio from monto) ;
```